# Finding the average velocity

Tags: arrays, for-loop, velocity

Hei I am trying to find the velocity of my position using the average velocity in each point. My position and time are put in an array, and I am using a for loop to find the velocity in each point. I am using this formula:

```
for i,j in zip(range(len(l1)),range(len(t))):
    v1.append((l1[i+1]-l1[i])/(t[j+1]-t[j]))
```

However, when using the formula, I get the error list index out of range. How can I fix this? Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 0):

Here `len(l1)` and `len(t)` will be the same as you are getting the position and time for each point. So only one loop variable is required. Also you are using `l1[i+1]`, this is why the error occurs.use `for i in range(len(l1)-1):v1.append((l1[i+1]-l1[i])/(t[i+1]-t[i]))`

Here if `len(l1)` is 4 then the loop will run for `i=0,1,2`
But in your code it will run `for i=0,1,2,3` and for `i=3`, `l1[i+1]` will cause the error.